# Cannot import ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i've just approached Google App Engine. I've joined a project without having a clue about how it work so i'm sorry if this question looks dumb.

My problem is that looking at the log, it says it cannot import ndb. I've looked up for that a bit and discovered this should be present by default in version 1.6.4 of the google app engine.

I've tried to import it from console and it doesn't work either. My installation of python and google app engine are clean, i did both today.

What should i do?

I'm working on windows with python 2.7 and google app engine 1.6.4.

This is the line of code giving me problems:

```
from wtforms.ext.appengine.ndb import model_form
```

Here is the error:

> INFO     2012-04-10 19:44:34,582 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 - ERROR    2012-04-10 19:47:05,239 wsgi.py:189] 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line
>   187, in Handle
>       handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line
>   236, in _LoadHandler
>       **import**(cumulative_path)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 676, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 1850, in load_module
>       return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 676, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
>       description)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 676, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
>       description)   File "C:\Users\chobeat\workspace\pappa Mi\py\main.py", line 38, in 
>       from py.comments import *   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 676, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 1850, in load_module
>       return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 676, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
>       description)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 676, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
>       description)   File "C:\Users\chobeat\workspace\pappa Mi\py\comments.py", line 20, in 
>       from py.form import IspezioneForm, NonconformitaForm, DietaForm, NotaForm   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 676, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 1850, in load_module
>       return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 676, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
>       description)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 676, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
>       description)   File "C:\Users\chobeat\workspace\pappa Mi\py\form.py", line 6, in 
>       from wtforms.ext.appengine.ndb import model_form ImportError: No module named ndb

Comment: You need to show us the stacktrace from the log - don't make us guess what you're seeing there.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import it like this:

`from google.appengine.ext import ndb`

If you just say `import ndb` you are missing out on some import path information. Don't be afraid to copy the code that is having trouble into your question. Often, that will provide the vital clue.

UPDATE:
WTForms is not included as part of the AppEngine SDK. You'll need to [install it](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/dev/crash_course.html#download-installation) on your system.

Comment: mmm ok, it works in console but stil doesn't work in the main project. I've downloaded it from a repository and it's supposed to work. Anyway i'm gonna edit the main post.

Comment: @Adam he is not trying to import ndb but the model_form from wtforms. which does not have a ndb package.

Comment: @aschmid00, yes, I get that. He added that nugget of information after I had answered the question, and I updated it to reflect that. i suspect that he hasn't installed WTForms.

Comment: i think he has but he is trying to import an `ndb` package that does not exist in wtforms. its `wtforms.ext.appengine.db`

Answer (score 0):

```
from wtforms.ext.appengine.ndb import model_form
```

can't work. wtforms does not have a ndb package.
it should be:

```
from wtforms.ext.appengine.db import model_form
```